# Copy/Paste from different workbooks - my code only copies one value

Tags: google-sheets

newbie here. My script only pastes the value of one cell.

```
 function copyValueandPaste()
{  
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID'); //Separate spreadsheet book
    var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('Payouts'); //Sheet tab with source data
    var sourceCellValue = sourcesheet.getRange('A9:J35').getValue(); // get A9 cell value
    var thisBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Active spreadsheet book
    var thisSheet = thisBook.getSheetByName('Template'); // Target sheet
    thisSheet.getRange('A7:J33').setValue(sourceCellValue); //Set value to target sheet A7 cell
}
```

I'm trying to copy a range and the results have pasted one value.

[image: Workbook View]

I want the script to paste the range A9:J35 from one workbook to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
var sourceCellValue = sourcesheet.getRange('A9:J35').getValue(); // get A9 cell value
[...]
thisSheet.getRange('A7:J33').setValue(sourceCellValue); //Set value to target sheet A7 cell
```

Change them for:

```
var sourceCellValue = sourcesheet.getRange('A9:J35').getValues(); // get all values in said range of cells.
[...]
thisSheet.getRange('A7:J33').setValues(sourceCellValue); // Set values to target sheet in said target cells range
```

↑ Notice the changes made to "[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)" and "[setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function copyValueandPaste()
{  
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID'); //Separate spreadsheet book
    var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('Payouts'); //Sheet tab with source data
    var sourceCellValues = sourcesheet.getRange('A9:J35').getValues(); // get A9 cell value
    var thisBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Active spreadsheet book
    var thisSheet = thisBook.getSheetByName('Template'); // Target sheet
    thisSheet.getRange(7, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceCellValue); //Set value to target sheet A7 cell
}
```

if you want to get multiple cell values, then that would be `getValues()`, which will give you a 2D array, like so: `[["value1", 2], ["value2", 3]...]`

Then, use `setValues()` but before in the `getRange()` you refer to the destination row, column, then the number of rows and the number of columns. Since `sourceValues` is now a 2D array, you get the number of columns from the first row `sourceValues[0]` and its `length`.